# Translate awk filtering to a windows command-line equivalent

Tags: powershell, awk, command-line

I need help with a very specific question. I need to replace the following UNIX-line to a windows equivalent without installation of third-party software.

```
awk -F ";" '$6 ~/2019-03-11/ {print}' myInputFile.csv >> myOutputFile.csv
```

What the line does:

It scans `myInputFile.csv`, where the column delimiter is a `;`, for the text `2019-03-11` in the 6th column and appends the line to `myOutputFile.csv`

Unfortunately, I cannot install gawk or anything like it on the client's machine.

I haven't used a windows machine for many years and am totally lost. :-(

Comment: Did you consider installing [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) or equivalent and use awk directly from `cmd`. You could also use some stuff from Windoze [Powershell](http://windows-powershell-scripts.blogspot.com/2009/06/awk-equivalent-in-windows-powershell.html). Also, my thoughts are with you.

Comment: Sorry just read saw your line that you cannot install cygwin.

Comment: does `awk` consider columns to be zero-1st or one-1st? most of the ways to do this in PoSh will be zero-1st. [*grin*] ///// also, if the solution by kvantour doesn't suit, please post a sample line of the input _and_ the desired output from that line.

Comment: Thanks all for the answers. I can't post anything from the original file (confidential) but it is a normal CSV file where the separated by semicolon (;) instead of comma (,). The column count starts with 1 in awk, so I want to filter the file by the 6th column.

Comment: Do it in Powershell.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer Thanks, I didn't know that powershell is a native part of Windows. Installing windows on my machine to test it out.

Comment: Windows 8+ is auto-installed.  Windows 7 is just an add-on through components

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you are after is the following in Powershell:

```
$ Get-Content .\myInputFile.csv | %{ if ($_.Split(';')[5] -match "2019-03-11") { $_; } } >> .\myOutputFile.csv
```

I will not put my hands in fire for the outcome of this.

If you want to call this from a bat-file, you have to do some [ugly-ness](https://superuser.com/questions/1050193/executing-a-powershell-script-through-batch-file).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I can't install anything on the machine. It needs to be a native batch script. :-(

Comment: @PeterKerschbaumer AFAIK Powershell is native to windows. (`Start > "Search Programs and Files" > type "Powershell"`)

Comment: @PeterKerschbaumer Just looked a bit arround, apparently you can call Powershell scripts from bat-files. I believe this is what you want. (updated answer with extra link)

Comment: @PeterKerschbaumer unless you're running ancient Windows versions, this is native.

Comment: @kvantour Thanks for the lesson. :-)

Comment: @PeterKerschbaumer I never programmed in Powershell before and never use Windows. Just had a look around. Interesting to see that MS evolved. So I did not teach you any lesson, I would more say "Thanks for the question".

Comment: The resulting array of the split method/operator is zero based, so it should be `...| %{ if ($_.Split(';')[5] -match "2019-03-11" ...`

Answer (score 1):

findstr.exe has rather limited RegEx capabilities, but this should be sufficient:

```
findstr "^[^;][^;]*;[^;][^;]*;[^;][^;]*;[^;][^;]*;[^;][^;]*;2019-03-11" <myInputFile.csv >>myOutputFile.csv
```

Another pure cmdline way (provided there **are** at least 7 columns):

```
For /F "tokens=1-6* delims=;" %A in ('findstr "2019-03-11" ^<myInputFile.csv') do @if "%F"=="2019-03-11" (>>myOutputFile.csv Echo %A;%B;%C;%D;%E;%F;%G)
```

In a batch file you'll have to double all percent signs.